# How to forward all internet connection to another machine

Tags: sockets, networking, forwarding

I want to forward all my tcp and udp connection from one of my port and pass them to another machine. Do you have any ideal ?

Comment: what OSes are involved? windows, linux? what are you really trying to do?

Comment: I prefer Independent from any platform, now i am working on linux, should I code a module for kernel?

Comment: this has nothing to do with python and apart from that solutions are easily findable using google

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution for all OSes (of courses).

A simple Google search gives you:

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/debian-linux/148854-forward-all-network-traffic-another-server.html

Comment: I want to code it with python using socket lib, but thanks it kindle me.